# Include a DLL file in project to avoid circular reference for deploying asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have the following solution structure

```
Test_Solution
 |_ Test1.csproj
       |_ Reference
              |_ SomeDll.dll
              |_ Others.dll
       |_ Files

 |_ Test2.csproj
       |_ Reference
             |_ Test1.dll
             |_ Etc.dll
       |_ Files
```

`Test1` project is a web application (asp.net with mvc 3).

`Test2` is a unit test project.

How you see, `Test2` has already a reference to Test1.dll (has some functions which are found in Test1 project)

For deploying application, I will create package using `msbuild` command (it will create `cmd` file and a ZIP and some XML files).

I want to include in that package also the `Test2.dll` but I cannot because of **circular reference** warning.

Why including that `Test2.dll`? Because I want to deploy whole package on a server and run a test (automated testing) using `Test2.dll` and install the application simultaneously.

What's the best way to do that ?

Comment: that isn't a circular reference unless Test1 also references Test2??

Comment: if I add `Test2` as reference to `Test1` project then `circular reference` occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a custom build that always builds both projects and packages both results into the zip

Comment: If I would know, I would never post my question :)

Comment: well, a quickstart on msbuild is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171479(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: I don't see the workaround to my problem. They treat a single file without using two dll files in same packages.

Comment: Now I really don't understand what you mean? There is no need to reference Test2 from Test1 just to include it in the package. You can use msbuild to build both projects and package the result however you like. The .csproj and solution files of visual studio are essentially msbuild-files (oversimplified, but still)

Comment: What I want is how to put `Test2` dll in `Test1` installation package. The MsBuild package will create package for `Test1` and I want to include also the `Test2` dll.